# Ajax Listeners Below First Listener Are Not Running

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

This is my HTML (problem is described below):

```
//Form 1 is called through a modal that is disconnected from form 2:
<div class="modal">
    <form action="/user" method="POST" id="form-1">
       <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
       <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

//Form 2 is appended in #form-1 listener
<div id="user-info" class="user-details">
    <p>Username: <%= user.username %></p>
    <% if(user.email) { %>
       <p>Email: <%= user.email %></p>
    <% } else { %>
    <form action="/user?_method=PATCH" method="POST" id="form-2">
       <input type="email" id="user-email" name="user-email">
       <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

The two ajax listeners/calls:

```
$('#form-1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('/user', user, function(data) {
        $('#user-info').append(
           `<p>Username: ${data.username}</p>
            <form action="/user?_method=PATCH" method="POST" id="form-2">
            <input type="email" id="user-email" name="user-email">
            <button>Submit</button>
            </form>`
        )
    });
});

$('#form-2').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/user',
        data: user,
        type: 'PATCH',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#user-info').append(
           `<p>Username: ${data.username}</p>
            <p>Email: ${data.email}</p>`
        )
        }
    });
});
```

The first one (`#form-1`) runs without a problem.
However, the second one (`#form-2`) is never run even though it is the only one that is called.
It only works when I comment out the first one (in other words, when I place it in the beginning of the script file. I think the second one is being ignored.
**Is there a way to listen to both forms simultaneously?**

Comment: Could you show your html code?

Comment: @RockySims I added HTML and edited my ajax to make it as closely similar to my original code. I didn't post my original code because it's too long and the indentation in Stack Overflow was messed up. But basically, this is the simplest version of my code.

Comment: I think the issue is that the second form doesn't exist yet when you try to wire up the `$('#form-2').submit(...)` handler. Try moving the `$('#form-2').submit(...)` paragraph to right after the `$('#user-info').append(...)` line.

Comment: @RockySims I am not trying to fill in both username and email one after the other. They are both separate things. A user can specify username today and choose to add email tomorrow. They are not chained together.

Comment: The `$('#user-info').append(...)` code (which creates `form-2`) only executes once `form-1`'s submit button is clicked... right?

Comment: @RockySims Yes, form 2 is created once form 1 is submitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238970/discussion-between-rocky-sims-and-user15344186).